# Emacs - LSP compile_command.json file?

Tags: c++, opencv, archlinux, emacs-lsp

I m in Arcolinux guyz, I am using clang-lsp in my Emacs.

I m new to programming but I need to prepare a project about Opencv(C++). Whenever I try a script , there is always warning like `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` file not found ? I have found some things in the internet like command_compile.json but they all uses cmake, when I try to do that, I got following error:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMDANS=ON /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/
CMake Error: The source directory "/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Can anyone help me ? it is really annoying.

One more question:

My opencv folder is in /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/ ,  but my project folder is in `~/Projects/opencv++/`

Thanks for attention.

Regards.

Comment: Does the directory it mentions have a CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: which one? ../opencv2/ or /Projects/opencv++/ ?

Comment: `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/`, since that's the folder the error is complaining about.